# Merging table output into a column in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, select, merge

I have an interesting problem to work in SQL that I really need help with.

What I need to do is to take a table, count the number of repeats/duplicates in a column, add those up and then spit the result out in a new column called "Count" matched to the column that was counted by record.

So, like.. If you had a table like:

```
Domain      | 
----------------
abc.com
abc.com
bca.com
bca.com
bca.com
ggg.com
```

I need it to output something like:

```
Domain     |   Count  
------------------------------
abc.com    |      2
abc.com    |      2
bca.com    |      3
bca.com    |      3
bca.com    |      3
ggg.com    |      1
```

Now, I have some code written by a very talented person. But, it's not in Transact SQL. Unfortunately, I do not have a great enough grasp with SQL to convert this to T-SQL at all.

(Static values replaced with blah)

```
create table tbl (blah, Domain)
insert into tbl ( blah query )

select tbl.Domain, t1.cnt
from   tbl
join   (select Domain, count(*) cnt
        from tbl
        group by Domain) t1
on     t1.Domain = tbl.Domain;
```

Any help transliterating this to Transact SQL would be very very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, this will work in SQL server I think, did you run your query in ssms?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f514/1/0

Comment: I did, but it choked on a parenthesis. Then when I tried to alter it a bit, it complained of a bad union with no "with" statement. I'm afraid my knowledge isn't complete in this regard.

Comment: There is no `union` in that.   This is valid TSQL.

Comment: You know what, I figured it out. Heh. Nothing more embarrassing then asking a question and then working out the answer, realizing how dumb the question sounds afterwards. lol

Answer (score 2):

That looks like valid tsql to me

But there is a shorter way
Window function

```
select Domain, count(*) over (partition by Domain) as cnt 
from tbl
```

Comment: That would be the whole thing, minus the join?

Comment: Did you even  try it?

Answer (score -1):

I actually figured it out after all your help. It was the query I was using to populate "tbl" in the first place that was hanging me up.

So, I did this:

```
use db;
drop table tbl;
select Domain into tbl from dbo.db;

select tbl.Domain, t1.Count
from tbl
join (select Domain, count(*) Count
from tbl
group by Domain) t1
on t1.Domain = tbl.Domain
```

And it worked. Thanks for all your help, guys and gals!

Comment: I mean, I guess this is okay if you have SQL 2000 and can't use Window functions, but I'd be weary of using this vs.the answer @paparazzo posted.  The window function is much cleaner.